# text content of bootstrap modal body flow outside.

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

text content of bootstrap modal body flows outside. when long text without any space.[image]
I need a solution.text content should not overlapping when text is long

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       dfsdfhsjkdfhsjkdhfjsdhfjkhsdjkfhjksdhfkjhdsjkfhsjkdhfjkshdfjkhsdjkfhjkdhfjkhsdkfhsjkdhfjksdhfkjhdskfhskdjhfkjshdkfhsjkdhfkjsdhfjkhsdjkfhsdjkfhjksdhfjkhsdjkfhsdjkhfjksdhfjkshdjkfhsdjkfhjksdhfjkshdfjkhsdjkfhjksdhfjkshdfjkhjkshdfjkshdjkfhsdkf
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because it's all one word, it's a rare case that you have a word that long without any spaces in between.
Put any normal words with spaces would break to the next line and won't flow.

Or add **word-break: break-all;** CSS rule to your modal body.

```css
.modal-body{
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       dfsdfhsjkdfhsjkdhfjsdhfjkhsdjkfhjksdhfkjhdsjkfhsjkdhfjkshdfjkhsdjkfhjkdhfjkhsdkfhsjkdhfjksdhfkjhdskfhskdjhfkjshdkfhsjkdhfkjsdhfjkhsdjkfhsdjkfhjksdhfjkhsdjkfhsdjkhfjksdhfjkshdjkfhsdjkfhjksdhfjkshdfjkhsdjkfhjksdhfjkshdfjkhjkshdfjkshdjkfhsdkf
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       dfsdfhsjkdfhsjkdhfjsdhfjkhsdjkfhjksdhfkjhdsjkfhsjkdhfjkshdfjkhsdjkfhjkdhfjkhsdkfhsjkdhfjksdhfkjhdskfhskdjhfkjshdkfhsjkdhfkjsdhfjkhsdjkfhsdjkfhjksdhfjkhsdjkfhsdjkhfjksdhfjkshdjkfhsdjkfhjksdhfjkshdfjkhsdjkfhjksdhfjkshdfjkhjkshdfjkshdjkfhsdkf
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding word-wrap: break-word to your .modal-body class will fix this.

```
.modal-body{
  word-break: break-all;
}
```